# How to highlight 1st, 2nd and 3rd highest from two column

Tags: excel-formula

I tried by selecting range then conditional formatting then cell value equal to then =large($C:$E,1) THEN fill golden color for 1st highest value. This formula applies to entire columns. I need help with applying formula within range i.e from  31 t0 41. I have values in column C i.e c31:c41 and column E i.e E31:E41 in percentage . I want golden color for 1st ,silver for 2nd and yellow for 3rd highest of two columns. Column D has names so column D can not be selected.

[SAMPLE EXCEL FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWLDL.png)

*sample data*

```
 C              D           E
 2.54%        vinu          5.69%
 119.90%       anand        157.34%
 49.32%       tanaji         7.39%
 82.28%       umesh        121.21%
-21.66%       chandu        94.10%
-60.45%       rajan        -25.71%
-20.12%       mule          37.02%
-16.05%       jafgtap       31.085%
-3.50%       kunal         282.62%
-3.27%       ramesh         14.58%       
-8.12%       rajesh          5.86%
```

Comment: Are you asking us to do your work for you? Where is your effort? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Take no offense, but you really should take the [Tour] and familiarize yourself with how this site works. Then edit your question to make it better.

Comment: have tried for three days. i tried by selecting the range then conditional formatting then cell value equal to then =large($c:$e,1) then color formatting for different colors with different position. it works but entire column is selected, i need help with selecting specific range.

Comment: Can you show some of the data that you are working with so that we can see if what you have tried can be modified to work?

Comment: have added" sample excel file".where is option to  load screenshot on site?

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells C31:C41 and insert a new formatting rule using a formula. This is the formula if your data starts in row 31 and the active cell is C31.

```
=C31=LARGE($C$31:$E$41,1)
```

Note the placement of the $ signs. It is important. Format this to be gold, then 
create two more rules with 2 and 3 as the last parameter for silver and bronze.

If the currently selected cell is on a different row than row 31, use the respective row number. My screenshot starts with row 1.

Select the cells in the worksheet, click the Format Painter on the Home ribbon and select cell E1 to apply the same rule to the cells in column E. In the screenshot I changed your sample numbers so column C has the third highest value.

[image]

Edit after comment:

If you explicitly want to exclude the values in column D, you can perform the Large() function on a limited list of ranges like this:

```
=LARGE(($C$31:$C$41,$E$31:$E$41),1)
```

Unfortunately, Conditional Formatting rules will not accept formulas with that level of complexity. The solution is to create three defined names with these formulas:

```
Gold     =LARGE((Sheet11!$C$31:$C$41,Sheet11!$E$31:$E$41),1)
Silver   =LARGE((Sheet11!$C$31:$C$41,Sheet11!$E$31:$E$41),2)
Bronze   =LARGE((Sheet11!$C$31:$C$41,Sheet11!$E$31:$E$41),3)
```

Then you can use three conditional formatting rules that compare the value in the range with the values of the defined names Gold, Silver and Bronze

[image]

Comment: this works really fine.but i want to completely ignore COLUMN D from range BECAUSE another work sheet has roll numbers instead of names in COLUMN D.

Comment: GETTING ERROR as "YOU MAY NOT USE reference operators(such as unions,intersections and ranges) or array constants for conditional formatting criteria ."

Comment: tried with function TOP 3,IT works well , but can not select different color for 1st highest, different for 2nd highest and  3rd.

Comment: getting same error,tiered with new formula.on you tube video no 1135 of EXCEL FUN compares ranks from two column.

Comment: My screenshot is from a working solution. Does that not work for you? What version of Excel? Share a sample file via a file sharing service and post a link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ys0A4E0tJTQ0x1VE4wTy1SWkk      SHARED  FILE LINK

Comment: The file does not use the named range solution I suggest in my post. Apply that. Because it works, as my screenshot shows.

Comment: I request you to apply formula to my file.i tried by copy paste your formula.

Comment: You WHAT? Sorry, this is not how this works. I showed you what you need to do. You will need to actually do it yourself.

Comment: request you to share your file

Comment: What are you struggling with? Did you follow the steps in my post? Create the range names and use the range names in the conditional formatting.

Comment: i am following exactly as your saying but its not working for me.

Comment: in your latest screenshot formula only shows range of column C   .((Sheet11!$C$31:$C$41,Sheet11!$E$31:$E$41),1) THIS RANGE IN NOT THERE IN FORMULA.

Comment: Do you see the named range formulas? Gold, Silver and Bronze? Can you read that it says to set up three named ranges? Did you do that? Then use these range names in conditional formatting. Did you do that?

Comment: new to named ranges .tried by watching YouTube videos to apply named ranges.screenshot for named ranges.

Comment: Sorry, but if you don't know these basic Excel concepts, you're on the wrong site. Go get some training and stop wasting people's time. This is a site for people who do expert programming, not rookies.

Answer (score 0):

This post has been quiet for a while, but maybe you can help me.
I have a large file with criteria across the top, labels on the left and scores in the middle. I've correctly modified the formula above for row based eval.
=B2=LARGE($B2:$X2,1) and =B2=LARGE($B2:$X2,2) and =B2=LARGE($B2:$X2,3)
I've noticed that if there are joint second largest values, then the third one doesn't work, and but the 4th one does work. It's not a major pain.

What I want to do now is apply the conditional formatting for the second row to all other rows (about 40). I can't see a way to copy the conditional formatting and I don't really want to enter the three of them 40 times.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)